# Spring boot META-INF/build-info.properties not in artifact

Tags: java, spring-boot

I would like to access my commit info in /info. Thing is, it works in IDE but there seems to be a problem while packaging the artifact, the file `META-INF/build-info.properties` is not packaged into jar! Any hint why?

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>build-info</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>package</phase>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <additionalProperties>
                <number>${buildNumber}</number>
                <job>${buildJob}</job>
            </additionalProperties>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: How do you load the file "in IDE"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove `<phase>package</phase>` from your execution and now do a `mvn clean install`. It should generate `META-INF/build-info.properties` file

Comment: Why do we need install ? IS there a way we can use another phase?

Answer (score 9):

```
     <build>
        <plugins>
           <plugin>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
              <configuration>
                 <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                 <executable>true</executable>
              </configuration>
              <executions>
                 <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                 </execution>
              </executions>
           </plugin>
```

Comment: use goal build-info before goal package or repackage to resolve the issue.

Comment: Maybe when it's bound to `package` it gets run "after" the packaging so doesn't get included, or something?  NB by default it is bound to the `generate-resources` phase: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/maven-plugin/build-info-mojo.html